# Optimization conditional price calculations to work without so many if branches

Tags: php, algorithm, conditional-statements, refactoring, calculation

How can I optimize these tons of if? Co2 payment begins from 131 and ends at 301 so until 131 is 0 and more than 301 is the same payment as 301. Tried with `array` but don't know how to get the price from the array if the number corresponds to co2 plus need to know fuel_id. Can't imagine how this code should look with `switch()`.

```
<?php
$co2 = '170'; // co2 number taking from DB

// fuel id taking from DB
(1, 'Petrol'),
(2, 'Diesel'),
(3, 'Electic'),
(4, 'Petrol / Gas'),
(5, 'Petrol / Hibrid'),
(6, 'Diesel / Hibrid'),
(7, 'Petrol / Hibrid / Plug-in'),
(8, 'Petrol / Hibrid / Gas'),
(9, 'Diesel / Hibrid / Plug-in');

echo $co2 ? 'Your co2 price is ' : '';

// Payment going from 131 co2
if($co2 >= 131 && $co2 <= 140){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '40.47' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '20.24';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '18.21';}
}else if($co2 >= 141 && $co2 <= 150){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '80.94' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '40.47';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '36.42';}
}else if($co2 >= 151 && $co2 <= 160){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '121.41' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '60.71';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '54.63';}
}else if($co2 >= 161 && $co2 <= 170){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '161.88' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '80.94';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '72.85';}
}else if($co2 >= 171 && $co2 <= 180){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '202.35' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '101.18';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '91.06';}
}else if($co2 >= 181 && $co2 <= 190){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '242.82' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '121.41';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '109.27';}
}else if($co2 >= 191 && $co2 <= 200){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '283.29' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '141.65';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '127.48';}
}else if($co2 >= 201 && $co2 <= 210){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '323.76' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '161.88';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '145.69';}
}else if($co2 >= 211 && $co2 <= 220){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '364.23' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '182.12';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '163.9';}
}else if($co2 >= 221 && $co2 <= 230){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '404.7' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '202.35';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '182.12';}
}else if($co2 >= 231 && $co2 <= 240){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '445.17' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '222.59';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '200.33';}
}else if($co2 >= 241 && $co2 <= 250){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '485.64' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '242.82';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '218.54';}
}else if($co2 >= 251 && $co2 <= 260){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '526.11' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '263.06';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '236.75';}
}else if($co2 >= 261 && $co2 <= 270){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '566.58' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '283.29';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '254.96';}
}else if($co2 >= 271 && $co2 <= 280){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '607.05' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '303.53';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '273.17';}
}else if($co2 >= 281 && $co2 <= 290){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '647.52' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '323.76';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '291.38';}
}else if($co2 >= 291 && $co2 <= 300){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '687.99' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '344';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '309.6';}
}else if($co2 >= 301){
    echo $fuel_id == 2 ? '728.46' : '';
    if($fuel_id == 1 || $fuel_id == 5 || $fuel_id == 7  || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '364.23';}
    if($fuel_id == 4 || $fuel_id == 8) {echo '327.81';}
}

echo $co2 ? ' $' : '';
?>
```

Comment: Does this code not work?

Comment: You want to shorten the code, is it?

Comment: RiggsFolly, this code is working for him. I think, he needs to optimize this code and shorten it for easy understanding and further updates.

@Kuvalda Please confirm whether the prices are hardcoded / fixed or it keeps on changing from time to time ?

Comment: so it must be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First, you have a mistake there with the fuel_id == 8 (I'm guessing it should be 9 in one of the options).
Second, you need to see what common figures you have in your different cases, to try and make the code as elegant and readable as possible

Comment: This data must be stored in the database, not in the code

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code works, but want to **optimise it**. No point to hold it in mysql cuz users give me only co2 number. Other numbers won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$co2 = '170';
$fuel_id = 1;

$type = match ( $fuel_id ) {
  2          => 't2',
  1, 5, 7, 8 => 't1578',
  4, 9       => 't49',
  default    => ''
};

$result = match ( true ) {
  $co2 >= 131 && $co2 <= 140 => [ 't2' => '40.47', 't1578' => '20.24', 't49' => '18.21' ],
  $co2 >= 141 && $co2 <= 150 => [ 't2' => '80.94', 't1578' => '40.47', 't49' => '36.42' ],
  $co2 >= 151 && $co2 <= 160 => [ 't2' => '121.41', 't1578' => '60.71', 't49' => '54.63' ],
  $co2 >= 161 && $co2 <= 170 => [ 't2' => '161.88', 't1578' => '80.94', 't49' => '72.85' ],
  // ...
  $co2 >= 301                => [ 't2' => '728.46', 't1578' => '364.23', 't49' => '327.81' ],
  default                    => [ 't2' => '', 't1578' => '', 't49' => '' ]
};

echo $result[$type] ?: 'no match';
```

So it seems that the structure of the data is as follows:

Each range (131 - 140, 141 - 150, etc.) has values for $fuel_id, which are a multiple of the values of the first entry (the one for the range 131 - 140).

So basically one can subtract the 130 from $co2, divide it by the length of each range (10), ceil the result and this gives a multiplier for these 'start' values in the first entry with the range 131 - 140.

Note that the result will be slightly off compared to the data in the OP (by 0,01 to 0,0x for some of the entries only).

```
$co2 = random_int(131, 400);
$fuel_id = random_int(1, 9);

$start = [
  1 => 20.24,
  2 => 40.47,
  3 => 0,       // no value for $fuel_id = 3 in the OP
  4 => 18.21,
  5 => 20.24,
  6 => 0,       // no value for $fuel_id = 6 in the OP
  7 => 20.24,
  8 => 20.24,   // or 18.21 ( 8 is used in two places
  9 => 18.21    // or 20.24   in the code of the OP )
];

$result = $start[$fuel_id] * ceil(( $co2 - 130 ) / 10);

echo "co2: $co2 & fuel_id: $fuel_id -> $result";
```

Answer (score 0):

Break down the logic.

You have a `$co2` value, and a rigid type map that is really just 3 categories repeated ad nauseum.

```php
class CO2MapThing {

    private const TYPE_HIGH = 0;
    private const TYPE_MED  = 1;
    private const TYPE_LOW  = 2;

    public function __construct(protected array $map) {}

    protected function mapType(int $type) {
        // FYI: your code has no 3/6/9, and 8 is listed twice, but this is how your code shakes out.
        switch($type) {
            case 2: return self::TYPE_HIGH;
            case 1:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8: return self::TYPE_MED;
            case 4: return self::TYPE_LOW;
            default:
                throw new \Exception("Unknown type: $type");
        }
    }

    public function getCost(int $co2, int $type) {
        foreach( $this->map as $key => $value) {
            if( $key > $co2 ) {
                return $this->map[$key][$this->mapType($type)];
            }
        }
    }
}

$map = [
    120 => [   '0.00',   '0.00',   '0.00' ],
    130 => [  '40.47',  '20.24',  '18.21' ],
    140 => [  '80.94',  '40.47',  '36.42' ],
    150 => [ '121.41',  '60.71',  '54.63' ],
    // ...
    PHP_INT_MAX =>
           [ '728.46', '364.23', '327.81' ]
];

$m = new CO2MapThing($map);

var_dump(
    $m->getCost(110,1),
    $m->getCost(120,1),
    $m->getCost(130,1),
    $m->getCost(990,1)
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "0.00"
string(5) "20.24"
string(5) "40.47"
string(6) "364.23"
```

If I actually knew what any of these values actually *meant* or how the dollar values are determined I might be able to come up with something a bit clearer, but I think that this is already a mile ahead of the other answers as far as clarity/readability/maintainability goes.

Answer (score 0):

Using a large battery of statically written numbers is one way to invite typos and human error into your algorithm.  It would be wiser to rely on mathematics rather than hand-coding so many conditional outcomes.

Another grand concern pertaining to human-readabilty and maintainability is all of the "magic numbers" in your script.  What are they? What do they mean? When can they be safely altered?  It may be a good idea to design some indicative constants at the top of your file for clarity.

All of that said, I noticed that your code comments indicate that the input data is being sourced from your database. (`// co2 number taking from DB` and `// fuel id taking from DB`)  I find myself agreeing with YourCommonSense, that this entire task can and should be processed in SQL.  The following scripts demonstrate how you can write a single static query to calculate the required output.  The beauty of this approach is that you probably won't ever need to alter the codebase (or not very often) because any tweaks that you might make will be upon the actual data (not the process).

Here are some basic tables (I'm not going to fuss with design strategy here; adjust how you wish)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    fuel_id INT,
    co2 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO users(name, fuel_id, co2) VALUES
('Abe', 5, 170),
('Bud', 4, 111),
('Cid', 2, 333),
('Dot', 1, 301),
('Eli', 8, 250),
('Fay', 9, 266);

CREATE TABLE fuel (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    cost DECIMAL(5,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO fuel(name, cost) VALUES
('Petrol',                    20.24),
('Diesel',                    40.47),
('Electic',                    0.00),
('Petrol / Gas',              18.21),
('Petrol / Hibrid',           20.24),
('Diesel / Hibrid',            0.00),
('Petrol / Hibrid / Plug-in', 20.24),
('Petrol / Hibrid / Gas',     20.24),
('Diesel / Hibrid / Plug-in',  0.00);

CREATE TABLE limitations (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    term VARCHAR(100),
    amount INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO limitations(term, amount) VALUES
('billable_co2_min', 130),
('billable_co2_max', 301),
('billable_co2_level_size', 10);
```

And now the processing SQL ([PHPize-online Demo](https://phpize.online/s/SC))

```
SELECT users.name,
       users.co2,
       fuel.name AS fuel_name,
       fuel.cost AS fuel_type_cost,
       ROUND(
           fuel.cost *
           CEIL(
            (
             GREATEST(
                 billable_co2_min,
                 LEAST(users.co2, billable_co2_max)
             )
             - billable_co2_min
            )
            / billable_co2_level_size
           ),
           2
       ) AS total
FROM users
JOIN fuel ON users.fuel_id = fuel.id
JOIN (SELECT amount AS billable_co2_min FROM limitations WHERE term = 'billable_co2_min' LIMIT 1) config1
JOIN (SELECT amount AS billable_co2_max FROM limitations WHERE term = 'billable_co2_max' LIMIT 1) config2
JOIN (SELECT amount AS billable_co2_level_size FROM limitations WHERE term = 'billable_co2_level_size' LIMIT 1) config3
```

My results may slightly differ from yours, but that is because I do not believe that `20.24` + `20.24` = `40.47`.  If you truly need inconsistent pricing, then you can/should create a pricing table in your database and JOIN with that.

Answer (score -1):

You could make the code more compact if you're on PHP version 8 or above using `match`:

```
echo match (true) {
    ($co2 < 131) => '',

    ($co2 <= 140) => 
        match ($fuel_id) {
            2 => '40.47',
            1, 5, 7, 8 => '20.24',
            4 => '18.21',
            default => '',
        },
    ($co2 <= 150) => 
        match ($fuel_id) {
            2 => '80.94',
            1, 5, 7, 8 => '40.47',
            4 => '36.42',
            default => '',
        },
    // etc for other boundary points on $co2
     
    default => '',
};
```

The conditions in the top-level `match` are evaluated in order, so there's no need to keep checking the lower bound (ie if it hasn't matched `$co2 <= 140` then we already know `$co2` is larger than 140 when we come to evaluate the next condition `$co2 <= 150`, and so on)

Comment: Still cannot be made configurable. This code is full of magic numbers.